# How on earth does this code work

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am a bit confused on how this code works. What it does is check whether the rook piece can move somewhere without getting attacked by another root.
Here's the code:

```
def rooks_are_safe(chessboard):
    n = len(chessboard)

    for row_i in range(n):
        row_count = 0
        for col_i in range(n):
            row_count += chessboard[row_i][col_i]
        if row_count > 1:
            return False

    for col_i in range(n):
        col_count = 0
        for row_i in range(n):
            col_count += chessboard[row_i][col_i]
        if col_count > 1:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: What's the input? What data do you have in `chessboard`?

Comment: This code seems to be useless imho.

Comment: I'm still learning, IMCoins

Answer (score 1):

A rook can move horizontally or vertically. So a rook can attack another rook if they're in the same row or column of the chessboard, i.e. there are at least two rooks in the same row or column.

This code seems to assume that the only pieces in the chessboard are rooks. If a square has a piece the value of the list element is `1`, otherwise it's `0`.

The first `for` loop goes through each row of the chessboard, counting the number of squares that have a piece in that row. If the count is more than `1`, the rooks are not safe, and it returns `false`.

The second `for` loop does the same thing, but goes by column instead of row.

If neither loop returns `false`, it means all the rooks are safe, and it returns `true` at the end.